# What are the CSS positioning properties relative to with position: absolute?

Tags: css, position, positioning

I know that `bottom`, `top`, `left`, and `right` with `position: absolute` sets that edge of the element to some distance away from that edge of the parent element. But how is the edge of the parent defined? Where is it in the box model? Does it include the border or the margin? The padding?

Comment: I would think inner padding.

Comment: I guess slapping together a jsFiddle or looking at the spec was too much trouble for you.

Comment: Put this in your CSS: `*{border: 2px dashed red;}` This results in you being able to see exactly how your page is build up, just mess around a bit. Use different colors for different elements to check what element has which border.

Also you might want to look up documentation about the box-model. This question is so general, are you looking for some kind of tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

It's within the border, but ignores the padding.

Let's show it with an example. [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtYXH/)

### HTML

```
<div>
  <span>absolute</span>
  regular
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #222;
}
span { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}​
```

Of course, an absolutely positioned element is positioned in relation to the first parent it comes across that is positioned with anything other than static. If the div in my example had no position set, the body of the fiddle would be used as that parent.